# How to prove that the determinant of this matrix is n! (by induction)

Tags: matrices, induction, determinant, factorial

A<sub>n</sub> is a **(n x n)** - matrix defined by:
a<sub>ij</sub> = **1**      if       i=j
       **-1**      if       j = i - 1
        **j<sup>2</sup>**     if       i = j + 1
        **0**      else
Prove by induction that det(A<sub>n</sub>) is **n!**

Comment: Have you tried Laplace expansion?

Comment: ^ To that end, have you tried *anything*? Please inform us where, specifically, you get stuck. Also, I hate "Piano Man", Billy.

Comment: There's a small problem: the conditions j = i – 1 and i = j + 1 are the same. So, what's $a_{ij}$?

Comment: should be for j<sup>2</sup> j = i + 1

Answer (score 0):

for n=3 the matrix is 
$\pmatrix{1 & 2^2 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 3^2 \\ 0 & -1 & 1}$

Calculating the det(A3) gives 14 $\neq$ 3!